# How to make my audio player randomly choose a file?

Tags: html

Right now in my site I'm using

```
<embed name="audio" src="audio1.mp3" loop="true" hidden="true" autostart="true">
```

to play audio files on the launch. I want to be able to have randomly choose from a collection of audio files in the directory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : Sorry I have misread the question.
It is impossible to select folder and get the files. This is due to security feature of the browser.

You may however

Create an array that stores your url sources. Then randomly select an item from the array

```
var source = [
"https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3",
"https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/wave.mp3",
"http://www.kozco.com/tech/organfinale.mp3"

];


 function randomPlay(){
    var toPlay = source[Math.floor(Math.random()*source.length)];
  var player = document.getElementById('player');
  player.src = toPlay;
  player.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
  player.play();
}
```

See this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/tq4ughrc/11/